# Setup a Eclipse Workspace With One Dynamic Web Project and Multiple Java Projects

Tags: eclipse, apache, jar, project, war

Can someone guide me to setup a web app project in Eclipse. I want to have a Dynamic Web Project and multiple Pure Java Projects. My Web project will contain JSPs and Java projects will contain Struts Action classes, Spring Bean, Hibernate Entities etc. I want to use those Java Projects as dependency to the WAR. I have done work in such environments, but haven't setup a workspace from the scratch. Can you please guide me or share a link?

Note: I want to use Apache Tomcat or Glassfish as server

Comment: Is my answer satisfying your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every project you can set the `JavaBuild Path properties`.

So suppose you have project1 that is dependent on project 2 and some other libraries provided as jars. Go to that option for project1, choose tab `Projects` and add project2 (that of course is already a eclipse project), than go to tab Libraries and clic on `Add external jars.`. You are done. This is not dependant by the nature of the project.

Specifically, since you have a Dynamic Web Project, you'll need to go also to `Deployment Assembly` and add project2 and your jars to the list of files needed by the server.